# umbraco 7 page displays wrong template

Tags: templates, umbraco, umbraco7

I use Umbraco 7.2.1
I have a document type called News with allowed 2 different templates: News (default) & Projects

I create a page and choose Project template for it. And it displays News template instead.

I tried the following to see what's wrong and came to nothing:

1. I set up a new page and choose Projects template - the page displays News template instead.
2. I changed the default template for this doc type to Projects and set up new page with different title - the new page still displays News template instead of default Projects.

It is not logical. Tried to refresh the cache but the problem persists.
I ensured the template is correct and it displays as such in the CMS as well.

I have another doc type which uses different templates and have no problem with that. Only with News/ Projects templates.

Completely not logical..

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check the structure on the doc type to check if both templates have been allowed to the News doc type. Typically when you create a new document type, only one template will be assigned. Alternatively, go to content, click on the properties tab and down the bottom you will see template. You should have dropdown enabling you to select which template you would like to use.

Comment: Thanks @Filth but I said before I chose Projects template for the doc typ in question. It's obvious I must have allowed both templates to this doc type if I was able to do it ;)